# Does anyone know why it isn't printing a sorted array?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to code a bubble sort algorithm in Python which has a flag that stops unnecessary passes.
The outcome I get is:

[5, 9, 4, 15, 3, 8, 11]

[5, 4, 9, 15, 3, 8, 11]

[5, 4, 9, 3, 15, 8, 11]

[5, 4, 9, 3, 8, 15, 11]

[5, 4, 9, 3, 8, 15, 11]

The correct outcome should show each pass of the bubble sort with the final pass being the sorted list but as you can see above this isn't the case.

```
numbers = [9, 5, 4, 15, 3, 8, 11]
numItems = len(numbers)
flag = True
i = 0
j = 0
while i < (numItems - 1) and (flag == True):
    flag = False
    for x in range(j, (numItems - i - 2)): 
        if numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]:
            temp = numbers[j]
            numbers[j] = numbers[j+1]
            numbers[j+1] = temp
            print(numbers)
            flag = True
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(numbers)
```

Comment: What were the results of your debugging attempts? Currently the answer is "because your algorithm is wrong".

Comment: Hi Neusha, as @mkrieger1 suggests, you might want to check your code. Trace through the loops and see where it stops sorting.

Comment: You should read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you increment j and once you finish the interior loop, j will remain (numItems - i - 2), you should reset it to 0 where you increment i, or loop with j without using x.
2. you were looping from j to n-i-2, you should loop to n-i-1.
3. you don't need the flag

after changes:

```
numbers= [9, 5, 4, 15, 3, 8, 11]
numItems = len(numbers)
i = 0
while i < (numItems - 1):
    for j in range(0, numItems - i - 1):
        if numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]:
            temp = numbers[j]
            numbers[j] = numbers[j+1]
            numbers[j+1] = temp
            print(numbers)
    i += 1
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Why is the flag unnecessary? I thought it might be an optimisation for bubble sort.